# change title of a graphic with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to VBA. I have this piece of code:

```
    Range("G37:G45").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Analisis!$G$37:$G$45")
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Analisis!$H$37:$H$45"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels

    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Sheets("Analisis").Range("F36")
```

Basically everything work but when I change the reference in cell F36, all the graphic changes apart from the title. Should I add something more?
Thanks

Comment: This code will run once only. So it just takes value from range F36 while it's running and add as chart title. It's not a formula that will be updated automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Caption = "=Analisis!F36"
```